# Battery not detected - Yoga 300-11iBR - Ubuntu LTS 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, battery, lts

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo Yoga 300 which comes with a built in battery. Everything works, but the system does not detect the battery. When entering `acpi -V` in terminal it displays:

```
Adapter 0: on-line
Cooling 0: soc_dts1 no state information available
Cooling 1: soc_dts0 no state information available
Cooling 2: B0DB no state information available
Cooling 3: INT3400 Thermal no state information available
Cooling 4: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 6: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 7: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 8: Processor 0 of 10
```

It does detect when I unplug the adapter.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in Xubuntu 16.10 (I also tried Xubuntu 16.04 and confirm it is a problem there as well). There are suspicious messages from dmesg:

```
[    2.575759] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000010) is beyond end of object (length 0xD) (20160422/exoparg2-427)
[    2.575775] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.BAT1._BIX] (Node f6091408), AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20160422/psparse-542)
[    2.575794] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Evaluating _BIX (20160422/battery-450)
```

I have googled this extensively and I think a fix to the acpi driver might be necessary, e.g.:

http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-acpi/msg69261.html

**UPDATE** I have confirmed that if you apply a patch similar to the one in the link above and build a custom kernel, the battery information is available! In my case I modified the patch a little bit to make sure the "_BIF" method is used and not the "_BIX" one. Hopefully this patch can eventually become part of an official kernel.

Answer (score 1):

The patch ([patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9337413](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9337413/)) is included in newer kernels.
The problem is solved ;-)
(more Info: Problem -was- a buggy firmware -BIX-method fails)

Battery detected again with kernel 4.10.rc5

Tested on: Lenovo Ideapad 300s-11IBR
(with Manjaro Linux, Kernel: 4.10.0-1-MANJARO)